# A sheaf for factorization

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, coherent-sheaves

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and let $X$ be the space of connected componens of $Spec (R)  $ with Zariski topology ( The boolean spectrum of $R $  )and let  for each $x\in X$ there exists a multiplicatively closed subset $S_x$ of $R$ such that for each $a\in R$ if $\frac{a}{1}=0_{S_x^{-1}R}$ for an $x\in X$, then there exists a closed and open subset $U$ of $X$ with $x\in U$ such that $\frac{a}{1}=0_{S_y^{-1}R}$ for every $y\in U$. How can we define a sheaf over $X$ such that  $S_x^{-1}R $ are its stalks with the property that if $ I $ is an ideal of $R $ such that $S_x^{-1}I$ can be factor as a finite product of comaximal ideals of $S_x^{-1}R $  for every $x\in X $, then this property holds for $I $?